# JSON Syntax wrong php function?

Tags: java, php, android, json

I have a problem with parsing my JSon Data in an Android application. I use a PHP script to get the Data from mysql and put it in a JSON. The problem is I can print the result and I see all the items that are in my table people.

[JSON data from database](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/190/jsona.jpg/)

but when the data is passed to the stringbuilder everything goes wrong. Afther parsing JSON's array say's that there is only one object in my Array?
I hope you can help me or give me some advice.

```
try{
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.1.10/getAllPeople.php");
    //httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    is = entity.getContent();
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection"+e.toString());
   }

//convert response to string
try{
      BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
       sb = new StringBuilder();
       sb.append(reader.readLine() + "\n");
       String line="0";
       while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                      sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        result=sb.toString();
        }catch(Exception e){
              Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
        }
//paring data
int id;
double Lat;
double Long;
String hulp = "";

v3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv3);
//v3.setText("Resultaat: " + result);

try{
      jArray = new JSONArray(result);
      for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){                 
             JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
             id = json_data.getInt("id");
             Long = json_data.getDouble("long");
             Lat = json_data.getDouble("lat");
             hulp = hulp + "\n" +  "Long: " + Long + " Lat: " + Lat;
             mob.add(new MobieleFlitsers(id,Long,Lat));
         }

      for(int i=0;i<mob.size();i++){

          hulp = " " + mob.size();
        }
        v3.setText(hulp);
      }
      catch(JSONException e1){
          Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Geen locatie's gevonden" ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      } catch (ParseException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I have added the PHP code because it stores the wrong JSON format.

```
        $q=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM people");

    //while($e=mysql_fetch_assoc($q))
    //$output[]=$e;
    //print(json_encode($output));
    //mysql_close();

    if (!$q) {
        echo "Could not successfully run query ($sql) from DB: " . mysql_error();
    exit;
    }

    if (mysql_num_rows($q) == 0) {
        echo "No rows found, nothing to print so am exiting";
        exit;
    }

    // While a row of data exists, put that row in $row as an associative array
    // Note: If you're expecting just one row, no need to use a loop
    // Note: If you put extract($row); inside the following loop, you'll
    //       then create $userid, $fullname, and $userstatus
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($q)) {
        $output[]=$row;
        print(json_encode($output));


    }
    mysql_close();
}
```

}

?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to complete jakeclarkson answer , in your PHP this

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($q)) {
    $output[]=$row;
    print(json_encode($output));
}
```

prints **the entire json so far at each row**, so basically, it print [1][1,2][1,2,3]... instead of only the last one. You simply need to extract your print after $output is complete:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($q)) {
    $output[]=$row;
}
print(json_encode($output));
```

Answer (score 2):

Having had a look at your image it appears that your JSON isn't valid:

```
[{"id": 1, "long": 5000, "long": 5000}][{"id": 1, "long": 5000, "long": 5001}]
```

This should be:

```
[{"id": 1, "long": 5000, "long": 5000}, {"id": 1, "long": 5000, "long": 5001}]
```

Note that in your current code **each** `Object` is wrapped in square brackets whereas there should only be one `Array` wrapping all the `Object`s which should be separated by commas.

Try putting your JSON output into [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) to double-check its validity.

Answer (score 0):

There is only one object in array. If you look at JSON carefully you will ysee that it contains concatenated  lot of arrays each containing single object.  And syntax is wrong.

Basically you terminated array after first object.